# The POM for org.springframework.osgi:org.springframework.osgi-library:libd:1.1.2.B is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, netbeans

I'm trying to build a **Spring Maven OSGI** application in **NetBeans**.

**Product Version:** NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (Build 201411181905)
**Java:** 1.8.0_60; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 25.60-b23
**Runtime:** Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_60-b27

It works well, until I add the **Spring-OSGI** dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.springframework.osgi-library</artifactId>
    <type>libd</type>
    <version>1.1.2.B</version>
</dependency>
```

**The Stack-Trace:**

```
The POM for org.springframework.osgi:org.springframework.osgi-library:libd:1.1.2.B is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:org-apache-commons-logging:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:cglib-2.2:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-aop-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-aspects-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-build-src-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-context-support-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-core-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-expression-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-framework-bom-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-instrument-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-instrument-tomcat-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-jdbc-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-jms-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-messaging-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-orm-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-oxm-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-test-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-tx-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-webmvc-portlet-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:spring-websocket-4.0.1.RELEASE:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running this in your root folder?

```bash
 mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true  -DdownloadJavadocs=true
```

This should work on both cmd and shell.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace shows that you are missing some other dependencies. 
If you look at this page you see, there are other required dependencies.

[Spring Source Enterprise Bundle Repository](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/library/version/detail;jsessionid=20040B651CD21ADE11DB1C4C9172D866.jvm1?name=org.springframework.osgi&version=1.1.2.B)